# Getting an error cannot read property "encodeParameters" of undefined

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethereumjs

I am running a node.js server but while running it, i am getting following error. what could be the possible reason?[image: error pic is attached]

Comment: Hello @suman, please provide more information about which tutorial you follow and what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have solved the earlier issue. i have send some token using the front end. but then in console it shows "Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number true to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "true""  and then exited the console.

Comment: you have to update your question with new error and maybe this error cause because of you didn't provide default account or unlock account for transfer token.

Comment: The reason is you trying to access `x.encodeParameters`, when `x` is undefined.